# SQL Server: Is it possible to UNION two tables in a SELECT statement without using a temp table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, union-all

I am creating a stored procedure that sets 3 variables based on queries and I have to return the `MAX` value of them. I am trying to do so without using a temp table however the following gives me the error `Incorrect styntax near ')'`

```
SELECT MAX(PermissionID)
FROM (SELECT @ContactPermission As PermissionID UNION ALL
      SELECT @GroupPermission As PermissionID)
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT MAX((SELECT @ContactPermission UNION ALL SELECT @GroupPermission))
```

and I get the error `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

I have also tried bypassing the variables and using a `UNION` in a subquery...

```
SELECT MAX(PermissionID)
FROM (SELECT PermissionID
        FROM PermissionContact
        WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
      UNION ALL
      SELECT PermissionID
      FROM PermissionGroup
      WHERE GroupID = @GroupID)
```

This also gives the `Incorrect syntax near ')'`

Any thoughts or suggestions? Are temp tables my only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your derived table an alias.

```
SELECT MAX(PermissionID)
FROM (SELECT @ContactPermission As PermissionID UNION ALL
      SELECT @GroupPermission As PermissionID) as T
```

Comment: So simple and quick... Thanks a ton, I will mark as answer in a few min when SO lets me.

Comment: +1 Can also use `SELECT MAX(PermissionID) 
FROM (VALUES(@ContactPermission,
             @GroupPermission)) T(PermissionID)`

Answer (score 1):

Or just use a case statement

```
Select Case When @ContactPermission > @GroupPermission 
       Then @ContactPermission Else @GroupPermission End PermissionID
```

or,

```
SELECT Case When c.PermissionID > g.PermissionId
        Then c.PermissionID Else g.PermissionId End
FROM PermissionContact c Cross Join PermissionGroup g   
Where c.ContactID = @ContactID
    And g.GroupID = @GroupID
```